# What's the difference between 秒钟 and 秒?

Tags: difference, time

Both of them seem to mean *a second*, according to both wiktionary and linedict.

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/秒钟#Chinese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A7%92%E9%92%9F#Chinese)

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/秒](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A7%92)

http://ce.linedict.com/dict.html#/cnen/entry/b90b963dcf6f45cead8a742525cd059f

Comment: Chinese A Comprehensive Grammar:Ch.25. Sentences are abbreviated and words omitted where context and co-text make the meaning clear,  similarly: 分钟 - 分，分钱 - 分，毛钱 - 毛，also  米 - 公米，升 - 公升

Answer (score 1):

If we're only talking about the English word *second*, then 秒钟 and 秒 don't really have any difference.

Perhaps you could think of 秒 as `sec`, as in `give me sec` or `I'll be there in a sec` & 秒钟 as `second`.

If we check out [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E7%A7%92%0D%0A)'s definition of 秒 we can see that it also includes other things beside a measurement for time, like:

> arc second (angular measurement unit)

and

> (coll.) instantly

Otherwise for general purposes: 秒钟 is just the lengthened form of 秒 & 秒 is just the shortened form of 秒钟.

Answer (score 1):

That is a question common to 134% of Chinese students (yeah, I just made up a nonsense number), and I personally think it's one of the most difficult issues in the Chinese language.

About 50% of the words are elastic in Chinese (check the concept here [How to deal with elasticity/flexibility in HSK vocabulary?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28769/how-to-deal-with-elasticity-flexibility-in-hsk-vocabulary))

To put it simple (very very simple), Chinese have words coming in one and two syllables that mean **exactly the same**. There are many theories trying to explain why that happens, and one of them (which I think is the easiest to understand) is about homophony causing ambiguity.

I'll give an example with the word 分 [fēn]. If someone says:

> 我还有一分。

One wouldn't be able to tell if he/she is saying "I still have one minute" or "I still have one cent", since 分 can mean both. To solve the ambiguity the words 钟 and 钱 should be added:

> 我还有一分钟。 I still have one minute. ("one 分 of hour")
>   我还有一分钱。 I still have one cent. ("one 分 of money")

So, the difference between 秒 and 秒钟 it's just that 秒钟 is the **complete word** for "second". But if you have context, you don't need the whole word. For example:

> A: 多少钱？  How much is it?
>   B: 一分。 One fen. (the context clears up that it's a "fen of money")